# py2exe not working for wxPython script

Tags: python

"py2exe" not working for "wxPython" script, I am getting no error or issue in the logs. However no executable created. Please find below file and logs. Is there any issue with file or program API calling?

Package using:

> import wx
>   import os
>   import string
>   import pickle
>   import subprocess
>   import json
>   import telnetlib
>   import re
>   import importlib

WxPython components used:

> Choice
>   OnPaint
>   StaticText
>   Button
>   TextCtrl
>   ListCtrl
>   SpinCtrl
>   CheckListBox
>   CheckBox

Help and related pointers much appreciated.

Thanks
Bharat

## File "setup.py"

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(name="wxTail",scripts=["ABCConfig.py"],)
====================================================

C:\Python27\programs\research>
C:\Python27\programs\research>
C:\Python27\programs\research>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
running build_scripts
creating build
creating build\scripts-2.7
copying ABCConfig.py -> build\scripts-2.7
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\bundle-2.7
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
creating python loader for extension 'unicodedata' (C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata
.pyd -> unicodedata.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'select' (C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> se
lect.pyd)
creating python loader for extension '_hashlib' (C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -
> _hashlib.pyd)
creating python loader for extension 'bz2' (C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> bz2.pyd)

*** finding dlls needed ***
*** create binaries ***
*** byte compile python files ***
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\StringIO.py to StringIO.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py to UserDict.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\__future__.py to __future__.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.py to _abcoll.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py to _strptime.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\_threading_local.py to _threading_local.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\_weakrefset.py to _weakrefset.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\abc.py to abc.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py to atexit.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\base64.py to base64.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\bdb.py to bdb.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\calendar.py to calendar.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py to cmd.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py to codecs.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\collections.py to collections.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\copy.py to copy.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py to copy_reg.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\difflib.py to difflib.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\dis.py to dis.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\doctest.py to doctest.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\dummy_thread.py to dummy_thread.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py to encodings\__init__.pyc
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7\enco
dings
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\aliases.py to encodings\aliases.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\ascii.py to encodings\ascii.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\base64_codec.py to encodings\base64_cod
ec.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\big5.py to encodings\big5.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\big5hkscs.py to encodings\big5hkscs.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\bz2_codec.py to encodings\bz2_codec.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\charmap.py to encodings\charmap.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp037.py to encodings\cp037.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1006.py to encodings\cp1006.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1026.py to encodings\cp1026.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1140.py to encodings\cp1140.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1250.py to encodings\cp1250.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1251.py to encodings\cp1251.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py to encodings\cp1252.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1253.py to encodings\cp1253.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1254.py to encodings\cp1254.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1255.py to encodings\cp1255.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1256.py to encodings\cp1256.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1257.py to encodings\cp1257.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1258.py to encodings\cp1258.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp424.py to encodings\cp424.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py to encodings\cp437.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp500.py to encodings\cp500.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp720.py to encodings\cp720.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp737.py to encodings\cp737.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp775.py to encodings\cp775.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py to encodings\cp850.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp852.py to encodings\cp852.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp855.py to encodings\cp855.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp856.py to encodings\cp856.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp857.py to encodings\cp857.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp858.py to encodings\cp858.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp860.py to encodings\cp860.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp861.py to encodings\cp861.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp862.py to encodings\cp862.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp863.py to encodings\cp863.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp864.py to encodings\cp864.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp865.py to encodings\cp865.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp866.py to encodings\cp866.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp869.py to encodings\cp869.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp874.py to encodings\cp874.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp875.py to encodings\cp875.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp932.py to encodings\cp932.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp949.py to encodings\cp949.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp950.py to encodings\cp950.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\euc_jis_2004.py to encodings\euc_jis_20
04.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\euc_jisx0213.py to encodings\euc_jisx02
13.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\euc_jp.py to encodings\euc_jp.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\euc_kr.py to encodings\euc_kr.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\gb18030.py to encodings\gb18030.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\gb2312.py to encodings\gb2312.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\gbk.py to encodings\gbk.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\hex_codec.py to encodings\hex_codec.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\hp_roman8.py to encodings\hp_roman8.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\hz.py to encodings\hz.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\idna.py to encodings\idna.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp.py to encodings\iso2022_jp.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_1.py to encodings\iso2022_jp
_1.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_2.py to encodings\iso2022_jp
_2.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_2004.py to encodings\iso2022
_jp_2004.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_3.py to encodings\iso2022_jp
_3.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_jp_ext.py to encodings\iso2022_
jp_ext.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso2022_kr.py to encodings\iso2022_kr.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_1.py to encodings\iso8859_1.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_10.py to encodings\iso8859_10.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_11.py to encodings\iso8859_11.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_13.py to encodings\iso8859_13.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_14.py to encodings\iso8859_14.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py to encodings\iso8859_15.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_16.py to encodings\iso8859_16.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_2.py to encodings\iso8859_2.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_3.py to encodings\iso8859_3.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_4.py to encodings\iso8859_4.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_5.py to encodings\iso8859_5.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_6.py to encodings\iso8859_6.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_7.py to encodings\iso8859_7.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_8.py to encodings\iso8859_8.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_9.py to encodings\iso8859_9.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\johab.py to encodings\johab.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\koi8_r.py to encodings\koi8_r.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\koi8_u.py to encodings\koi8_u.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\latin_1.py to encodings\latin_1.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_arabic.py to encodings\mac_arabic.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_centeuro.py to encodings\mac_centeu
ro.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_croatian.py to encodings\mac_croati
an.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_cyrillic.py to encodings\mac_cyrill
ic.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_farsi.py to encodings\mac_farsi.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_greek.py to encodings\mac_greek.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_iceland.py to encodings\mac_iceland
.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_latin2.py to encodings\mac_latin2.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_roman.py to encodings\mac_roman.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_romanian.py to encodings\mac_romani
an.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mac_turkish.py to encodings\mac_turkish
.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mbcs.py to encodings\mbcs.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\palmos.py to encodings\palmos.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\ptcp154.py to encodings\ptcp154.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\punycode.py to encodings\punycode.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\quopri_codec.py to encodings\quopri_cod
ec.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\raw_unicode_escape.py to encodings\raw_
unicode_escape.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\rot_13.py to encodings\rot_13.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\shift_jis.py to encodings\shift_jis.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\shift_jis_2004.py to encodings\shift_ji
s_2004.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\shift_jisx0213.py to encodings\shift_ji
sx0213.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\string_escape.py to encodings\string_es
cape.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\tis_620.py to encodings\tis_620.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\undefined.py to encodings\undefined.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\unicode_escape.py to encodings\unicode_
escape.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\unicode_internal.py to encodings\unicod
e_internal.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16.py to encodings\utf_16.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16_be.py to encodings\utf_16_be.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py to encodings\utf_16_le.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_32.py to encodings\utf_32.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_32_be.py to encodings\utf_32_be.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_32_le.py to encodings\utf_32_le.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_7.py to encodings\utf_7.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py to encodings\utf_8.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8_sig.py to encodings\utf_8_sig.pyc

byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\uu_codec.py to encodings\uu_codec.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\encodings\zlib_codec.py to encodings\zlib_codec.p
yc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\fnmatch.py to fnmatch.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\functools.py to functools.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py to genericpath.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\getopt.py to getopt.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\gettext.py to gettext.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\hashlib.py to hashlib.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\heapq.py to heapq.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py to inspect.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\io.py to io.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\keyword.py to keyword.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\linecache.py to linecache.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\locale.py to locale.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py to logging\__init__.pyc
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7\logg
ing
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py to ntpath.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\opcode.py to opcode.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py to optparse.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\os.py to os.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\os2emxpath.py to os2emxpath.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\pdb.py to pdb.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py to pickle.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\posixpath.py to posixpath.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\pprint.py to pprint.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\quopri.py to quopri.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\random.py to random.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\re.py to re.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\repr.py to repr.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\shlex.py to shlex.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\sre.py to sre.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\sre_compile.py to sre_compile.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\sre_constants.py to sre_constants.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py to sre_parse.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\stat.py to stat.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\string.py to string.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\stringprep.py to stringprep.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\struct.py to struct.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py to subprocess.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py to tempfile.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\textwrap.py to textwrap.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\threading.py to threading.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\token.py to token.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\tokenize.py to tokenize.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py to traceback.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\types.py to types.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\__init__.py to unittest\__init__.pyc
creating C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7\unit
test
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py to unittest\case.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py to unittest\loader.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py to unittest\main.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\result.py to unittest\result.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\runner.py to unittest\runner.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\signals.py to unittest\signals.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\suite.py to unittest\suite.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\unittest\util.py to unittest\util.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\warnings.py to warnings.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\lib\weakref.py to weakref.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\_hash
lib.py to _hashlib.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\bz2.p
y to bz2.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\selec
t.py to select.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\programs\research\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\unico
dedata.py to unicodedata.pyc
*** copy extensions ***
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
*** copy dlls ***
copying C:\Python27\w9xpopen.exe -> C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
copying C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll -> C:\Python27\programs\research\dist
setting sys.winver for 'C:\Python27\programs\research\dist\python27.dll' to 'wxT
ail'

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll

C:\Python27\programs\research>
```

Comment: py2exe is  very old ! try Pyinstaller.

Comment: I tried with Pyinstaller, executable is successfully created. However its not working, while execution its not showing any message (silently finished without any print).